# CD/DVD drive not found in VirtualBox Windows 7 guest / Ubuntu host

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Windows 7 in VirtualBox to try an Spanish Version for a customer.

I'm using an ISO file with the Windows 7 image. After the machine is done loading the installation files, I get this error:

[image: screenshot of the error]

Basically the translation is:

> Could not find the controller of the CD or DVD device. If you have any CD, DVD or USB that might have the controller, insert it now

After I click `Accept` it shows that blank list box you see behind the dialog. I cannot continue to install Windows.

I have tried in configuring the virtual machine with fixed size virtual drive, with virtual hard disks etc., but I always get this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that the ISO in the drive is boot able and working properly?